# Search for string on WP7 Bing Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Is it possible to make a query to the Bing Maps with a string (Being a location) ?

I have a user entered field, then I want the user to be able to press a button and then a certain string is put into Bing maps (Maybe tombstone my app meanwhile?) Something like

```
string UserLocation = "Wall Street New York";
BingMapsApi.Search(UserLocation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query Bing maps via the [Bing Maps Rest API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx), it sounds like you want to [find a location via a search string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx). For example, this query find the Microsoft offices;

> http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/1%20Microsoft%20Way%20Redmond%20WA%2098052?o=xml&key=BingMapsKey

Comment: I want it to work on WP7, this seems to just be a bing maps query, not just for WP7

Comment: No, this is a RESTful service, anything that supports HTTP can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the maps: parameter, and use a `WebBrowserTask` to navigate to the result, as if it were a URL.

```
string location = "maps:" + SelectedLocation.Street + " " + SelectedLocation.PostalCode;
location = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(location);
WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.URL = location;
task.Show();
```